# How to recurse directory tree to operate on lower most directories first and highest directories last?

Tags: bash, find, rsync, zsh

I am needing to write a script that will move files to a destination location (off volume), remove the original file and directories and then move them back to their original location while preserving all attributes.

The concept is rather simple algorithmically, however the real hangup I'm having is recursing the tree properly when I'm using rsync.

So far it appears that `rsync -axvvES --remove-source-files source_directory /destination/` is the most efficient solution for copying files over, however, as noted, I cannot simply allow rsync to recurse the tree itself due to size constraints.  Ultimately I think `find` can be used to drill down and then allow `rsync` to run, however **how can I descend to the lowest point first with `find` in order to accomplish this goal?**

UPDATE:

Ultimately this seemed to do the trick satisfactorily:

```
echo -e "Moving over... "
rsync -axvES --remove-source-files ${SRC_FILE_AND_PATH} ${DESTINATION_PATH}/
echo -e "Bringing back... "
rsync -axvES --remove-source-files ${DESTINATION_PATH}/${SRC_BASENAME} ./
```

It does leave folders in the working directory, but since it does overwrite attributes correctly on the initial folder on the move back, it's satisfactory and in the end I can just rm the empty remaining directories.

Comment: I don't understand what is unsatisfactory with your current command. You need to create destination directories first and then populate them anyway, what do you hope to do differently? If the problem is the order of deletion, what exactly do you want, and isn't any of the `--delete-*` options suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`find`](http://man.cx/find) command has a `-depth` switch which makes it behave like you ask for.